# Q: KNN in R -- strange behavior

Tags: r, knn

Does anyone know why the following KNN R code gives different predictions for different seeds? 
This is strange as K<-5, and thus the majority is well defined. In addition, the floating numbers are not that small to fall under a precision of data problem.
(remark: I know the test is weirdly different from the training. This is only a synthetic example created to demonstrate the strange KNN behavior)

```
library(class)

train <- rbind(
  c(0.0626015,  0.0530052,  0.0530052,  0.0496676,  0.0530052,  0.0626015),
  c(0.0565861,  0.0569546,  0.0569546,  0.0511377,  0.0569546,  0.0565861),
  c(0.0538332,  0.057786,   0.057786,   0.0506127,  0.057786,   0.0538332),
  c(0.059033,   0.0541484,  0.0541484,  0.0501926,  0.0541484,  0.059033),
  c(0.0587272,  0.0540445,  0.0540445,  0.0505076,  0.0540445,  0.0587272),
  c(0.0578095,  0.0564349,  0.0564349,  0.0505076,  0.0564349,  0.0578095)
)
trainLabels <- c(1,
                 1,
                 0,
                 0,
                 1,
                 0)
test  <- c(0.1923241, 0.1734074, 0.1734074, 0.1647619, 0.1734074, 0.1923241)

K <- 5

set.seed(494139)
pred <- knn(train=train, test=test, cl = trainLabels, k=K)
message("predicted: ", pred, ", seed: ", seed)
# **predicted: 1**, seed: 494139

set.seed(5371)
pred <- knn(train=train, test=test, cl = trainLabels, k=K)
message("predicted: ", pred, ", seed: ", seed)
# **predicted: 0**, seed: 5371
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? The R code has one bug in it: The last test pretends to use the same seed as the second to last, but it doesn't because it's  not set. Is that the source of your confusion?

Answer (score 1):

The `knn` function calls an underlying [C function](https://github.com/cran/VR/blob/bee1fa0b41389c582b07bb2de194238fe5e85783/class/src/class.c) (line 122) called `VR_knn`, which includes a step that introduces "fuzz" or a small value (epsilon, EPS). Looks like your example parameter values may be hitting up against that "fuzz" step. Evidence for this is the fact that rounding your values to 4 digits yields consistency. As such:

```
library(class)
train <- rbind(
  c(0.0626015,  0.0530052,  0.0530052,  0.0496676,  0.0530052,  0.0626015),
  c(0.0565861,  0.0569546,  0.0569546,  0.0511377,  0.0569546,  0.0565861),
  c(0.0538332,  0.057786,   0.057786,   0.0506127,  0.057786,   0.0538332),
  c(0.059033,   0.0541484,  0.0541484,  0.0501926,  0.0541484,  0.059033),
  c(0.0587272,  0.0540445,  0.0540445,  0.0505076,  0.0540445,  0.0587272),
  c(0.0578095,  0.0564349,  0.0564349,  0.0505076,  0.0564349,  0.0578095)
)
trainLabels <- c(1,1,0,0,1,0)
test  <- c(0.1923241, 0.1734074, 0.1734074, 0.1647619, 0.1734074, 0.1923241)
K <- 5

train <- round(train,4)

seed <- 494139
set.seed(seed)
pred <- knn(train=train, test=test, cl = trainLabels, k=K)
message("predicted: ", pred, ", seed: ", seed)
# predicted: 0, seed: 494139

seed <- 5371
set.seed(seed)
pred <- knn(train=train, test=test, cl = trainLabels, k=K)
message("predicted: ", pred, ", seed: ", seed)
# predicted: 0, seed: 5371
```