# Q: KNN in R — strange behavior

Tags: r, knn

Does anyone know why the below KNN R code gives different predictions for different seeds? This is strange as K<-5, and thus the majority is well defined. In addition, the floating numbers are large -- so no precision of data problem arises (like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900958/q-knn-in-r-strange-behavior/38929227#38929227)).

```
library(class)

set.seed(642002713)
m = 20
n = 1000
from = -(2^30)
to = -(from)
train = matrix(runif(m*n, from, to), nrow=m, ncol=n)
trainLabels = sample.int(2, size = m, replace=T)-1
test = matrix(runif(n, from, to), nrow=1)

K <- 5

seed <- 544336746
set.seed(seed)
pred_1 <- knn(train=train, test=test, cl = trainLabels, k=K)
message("predicted: ", pred_1, ", seed: ", seed)
#predicted: 0, seed: 544336746

seed <- 621513172 
set.seed(seed)
pred_2 <- knn(train=train, test=test, cl = trainLabels, k=K)
message("predicted: ", pred_2, ", seed: ", seed)
#predicted: 1, seed: 621513172
```

A manual check:

```
euc.dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))
result = vector(mode="numeric", length=nrow(train))
for(i in 1:nrow(train)) {
  result[i] <- euc.dist(train[i,], test)
}
a <- data.frame(result, trainLabels)
names(a) = c("RSSE", "labels")
b <- a[with(a, order(sums, decreasing =T)), ]
headK <- head(b, K)
message("Manual predicted K: ", paste(K," class:", names(which.max(table(headK[,2])))))
#Manual predicted K: 5  class: 1
```

would give the prediction 1, with the Top K(=5) RSSE:

```
RSSE             labels
28479706980      1
28472893026      0
28063242772      1
27966740954      1
27927401005      1
```

so, majority is well defined + no problem of small float difference in RSSE.

Comment: Quite interesting: going to test few ideas - data are not scaled and centered. does it persist if you preprocess them? Try kNN from 'caret' package. if it persists...I will test it when I get home

Comment: There is nothing stochastic in the R code for `knn()`, so the difference has to be in the C routine `VR_knn()` in `class.c` that gets called by it.

Answer (score 0):

When I scale and center the data - **including the test set!**, then I get both predictions 0.

My preprocessing:

```
sc<-function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}
train<-apply(train,1,sc)
train<-t(train)
test<-apply(test,1,sc)
test<-t(test)
```

and obtain:

```
> seed <- 544336746
> pred_1 <- knn(train=train, test=test, cl = trainLabels, k=K)
> message("predicted: ", pred_1, ", seed: ", seed)
predicted: 0, seed: 544336746

> seed <- 621513172
> pred_2 <- knn(train=train, test=test, cl = trainLabels, k=K)
> message("predicted: ", pred_2, ", seed: ", seed)
predicted: 0, seed: 621513172
```

manual check that I edited to this form

```
a <- data.frame(result, trainLabels)
names(a) = c("RSSE", "labels")
b <- a[with(a, order(a$RSSE)), ]
headK <- head(b, K)
message("Manual predicted K: ", paste(K," class:", names(which.max(table(headK[,2])))))
Manual predicted K: 5  class: 0
```

and results:

```
       RSSE labels
3  43.48199      0
17 43.61283      1
7  43.63948      1
8  43.69730      0
19 43.78931      0    
6  43.88009      0
```

Comment: Thanks.
(1) When I ran the "manual check" code on the scaled and centered data you've create, I got a predicted "class: 1" -- while you got "class 0" -- strange; 
(2) Are you sure one must scaled and centered before using KNN?

Comment: I think you need to: train<-apply(train,**2**,sc), and remove: train<-t(train). Then you will get the predicted class 1, which is the same as the manual check.

Comment: Well with the scaling it is ambiguous as they talk about it [here] (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121886/when-should-i-apply-feature-scaling-for-my-data) . But for example my teacher prof Gorban said to always scale....also your data could be different, because `set.seed` wouldn't apply to second random draw for the test data, so we have different test data..if I set seed to 5 before drawing test from `runif` then I get class 0 again...I thought you were mainly after consistency of kNN...

Comment: Well the data is in 20x1000 matrix, so I gathered its 20 objects and 1000 features per one? As there were 20 labels...so I went row-wise...so if you had 1000x20 and I had 20x1000 mayba thats the confusion :)

Comment: Are you happy with it now?

Comment: Ok I went through the manual check as well..I updated my answer to keep formatting. Btw in your manual check, when creating **b** what is the sums term in order? Also do you not want to sort them increasing, so in head you have 5 closest observations to **test** which in fact will classify it as 0? You are looking at 5 most distant ones (with highest euclidian distance...)

Comment: Please see my reply in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941780/q-knn-in-r-strange-behavior)

Comment: I dont see how the link explains this. I think you have a mistake in the hand check when sorting them in descending order. You want to inspect slowest distances! Please have a look at the changes I proposed.