# Q: KNN in R — strange behavior

Tags: r, knn

(in continuation to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932289/q-knn-in-r-strange-behavior))

Does anyone know why the below KNN R code gives different predictions for different seeds? This is strange as K<-5, and thus the majority is well defined. In addition, the floating numbers are large -- so no precision of data problem arises + the data is scaled and centered.

```
library(class)

from = -(2^30)
to = -(from)

seed <- -229881389  
set.seed(seed)

K <- 5
m = as.integer(runif(1, K, 20))   
n = as.integer(runif(1, 5, 1000)) 
train = matrix(runif(m*n, from, to), nrow=m, ncol=n)
trainLabels = sample.int(2, size = m, replace=T)-1
test = matrix(runif(n, from, to), nrow=1)

sc<-function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}
train<-apply(train,2,sc)

test<-t(apply(test,1,sc))

seed <-  as.integer(runif(1, from, to))
set.seed(seed)
pred_1 <- knn(train=train, test=test, cl = trainLabels, k=K)
message("predicted: ", pred_1, ", seed: ", seed)

seed <- as.integer(runif(1, from, to))
set.seed(seed)
pred_2 <- knn(train=train, test=test, cl = trainLabels, k=K)
message("predicted: ", pred_2, ", seed: ", seed)
```

A manual check:

```
euc.dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))
result = vector(mode="numeric", length=nrow(train))
for(i in 1:nrow(train)) {
  result[i] <- euc.dist(train[i,], test)
}
a <- data.frame(result, trainLabels)
names(a) = c("RSSE", "labels")
b <- a[with(a, order(result, decreasing =T)), ]
headK <- head(b, K)
message("Manual predicted K: ", paste(K," class:", names(which.max(table(headK[,2])))))
print(b)
```

would give the prediction 0, for the Top K(=5).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Q: KNN in R — strange behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932289/q-knn-in-r-strange-behavior)

Comment: It's not a duplicate as this question is doing scaled and centered (while [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932289/q-knn-in-r-strange-behavior) isn't)

Comment: By the way, for a reproducible example you should not use a seed which is random itself... That said, there is some randomness in applying knn, which is needed to handle ties. So, using different seeds you get different results.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes:

- You have a mistake in using wrong test set in the knn - use test_ as the centered,scaled variable.
- in creating **b** there is no variable *sums*, you can just use simple order that orders in increasing order by default.
- The order has to be **increasing** in distance, as you are looking for nearest neighbours, look at smallest distance.
- using **set.seed** before a code that has nothing stochastic (random) makes effect on the evaluation.

So it's basically same as I tried to explain in the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932289/q-knn-in-r-strange-behavior/38932772?noredirect=1#comment65238587_38932772).

Comment: Thanks Jan. 
Indeed there was a bug with 'test_', 'b' and the sorting. I've emended the original post accordingly. 
As for the first seed, it is needed to set the random data creation. 
Speaking of it, I've changed it (in the original post) to -634500985.
Take a look what's happened. Is it again the [C function fuzz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900958/q-knn-in-r-strange-behavior/) problem? (although EPS is [defined (line 23)](https://github.com/cran/VR/blob/bee1fa0b41389c582b07bb2de194238fe5e85783/class/src/class.c) as 1e-4)